# Are there any dogs in Hogwarts Legacy?

Tags: hogwarts-legacy

I've seen lots of cats in the Hogwarts castle as well as many other animals around the Hogwarts grounds, but what about dogs?

Are there any dogs in Hogwarts Legacy? Just normal domesticated dogs.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Be0qK3c6gPs - There are ["Mongrel dogs"](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Mongrel_Dog)

Comment: Not yet, but I wouldn't be surprised if Fluffy showed up later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the answer is "no".
According to [Gamepur](https://www.gamepur.com/guides/can-you-pet-the-dogs-and-cats-in-hogwarts-legacy-answered):

> Sadly, there don’t seem to be any dogs in the game and we doubt it would come later, but in the meantime, you can go make yourself a cat friend.